# Why is Audio Saving to Storage/Emulated/0 when using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() in android studio

Tags: java, android, audio

I have code that saves a text to speech conversion into an audio file. I am using the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads), to make a new folder or save the audio file in the folder already. This means it should be accessible in google files right? However, it is not visible in google files, and it saves to storage/emulated/0, which to my knowledge is not accessible in google files.

If there are any errors in this code that can be fixed to move it to an accessible place in google files, please tell me!

Code:

```
private void createFile() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE);
        }
    }

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Text To Speech Audio");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = folder.mkdirs();
        if (!isDirectoryCreated)
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't create directory to save the Audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    folder.mkdirs();
    mAudioFilename = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + translateTo + "-" + languageCode + mUtteranceID + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav";
}

private void saveAudioToFile(String textToSpeak) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        speech.synthesizeToFile(textToSpeak, null, new File(mAudioFilename), mUtteranceID);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved to " + mAudioFilename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, mUtteranceID);
        speech.synthesizeToFile(textToSpeak, hm, mAudioFilename);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved to " + mAudioFilename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not react to my remark in your other post. So i could make the same remarks again.

Comment: How would I return the synthesizeValue though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working code for Android 14 (API 34):
To use the code **without** write permissions for API34 **and** e.g. API 29, you should not choose `Download` as destination folder, but e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/(YOUR_PACKAGE)`. Thus

```java
tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {    
  @Override public void onInit(int status) {
     tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);  //or an other language
     int answer = tts.synthesizeToFile("Hello world", null, new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalMediaDirs()[0].getAbsolutePath()+"/HelloWorld.wav"), "");
     if (answer==0) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WAV file successful created and stored in /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/(YOUR_PACKAGE)/HelloWorld.wav.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } else {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WAV file NOT created or stored.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
   }
}, "com.google.android.tts");  //I had no success without this line, except in the emulator. Must be one of your TTS engines.
```

Comment: `The download folder is no longer accessible as a storage location for files` Wrong. On Android 13, 14 one can create files there even without needing any permission.

Comment: @blackapps You are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Please read your answer. First it is no answer to OP's question. Second: what you say is not true.

Comment: 1) Yes, but the OP asked almost the same question three times within 5 days, this answers his **original** problem, which I'm sure he still has.
2) ??? I tried API29+`Download`->don't work, API29+`Android/media/(YOUR_PACKAGE)`->works, API34+`Download`->works, API34+`Android/media/(YOUR_PACKAGE)`->works. Can you explain what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: You say that for 34 you cannot use Download directory without permission. For the rest: @AKD2022 has the nasty habit not to react.

Comment: I said that until an hour ago. But I edited my answer to: If you want a solution for 34 **and** 29, you have to choose e.g. `Android/media/...`. This does not exclude that a solution for 34 **alone** would also work with `Download`.

Comment: There is still written that for 34 you cannot use Download dir without permission.

Comment: So this is a subtle linguistic problem. I would like to say: To build a (single) app that works (in parallel) for API 29 and 34 devices, you should choose `Android/Media/...`. Since English is not my native language (in my country we speak 4 languages, none is English): How do you think I should improve this sentence in my answer?

Comment: Its ok now. You do your best. I got it. It's time OP reacts. Meanwhile i will puzzle my brain for a country with four languages..