# How to ask for write_external_storage_permissions in this code block in android studio

Tags: java, android, permissions

I have this function that generates an audio file on a button click. I'm having trouble asking for permissions for writing the folder for external storage. I already have something, but i'm not getting a dialog that asks for it. It would be helpful if someone adds the function to my existing code.

Translating and generating audio file:

```
private void initializeTextToSpeech(Locale selectedLocale) {
    speech = new TextToSpeech(getContext(), status -> {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = speech.setLanguage(selectedLocale);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Language not supported");
                // Handle the case where the language is not supported
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Text-to-Speech initialized");
                // Now that TextToSpeech is initialized and language is set, let's synthesize text to an audio file
                String textToSpeak = translatedText;
                saveAudioToFile(textToSpeak);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Text-to-Speech initialization failed");
            // Handle Text-to-Speech initialization failure
        }
    });
}

private void createFile() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE);
        }
    }

    folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Text To Speech Audio");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = folder.mkdirs();
        if (!isDirectoryCreated)
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Can't create directory to save the Audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    folder.mkdirs();
    mAudioFilename = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + languageCode + "-" + translateTo + mUtteranceID + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav";
}

private void saveAudioToFile(String textToSpeak) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        speech.synthesizeToFile(textToSpeak, null, new File(mAudioFilename), mUtteranceID);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved to " + mAudioFilename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, mUtteranceID);
        speech.synthesizeToFile(textToSpeak, hm, mAudioFilename);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved to " + mAudioFilename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

What I'm Calling:

```
generateAudioBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        initializeTextToSpeech(selectedLocale);
        createFile();
    });
```

Comment: What is Android version of used device?

Comment: @blackapps I used a device with android 13

Comment: On an Android 13 device you should not ask for that write permission as you can write by default in all public directories on external storage.

Comment: @blackapps, so would the code I have work for asking for permisison on devices that need it

Comment: Well let that wait first. Make it work for 13+ first. Remove all your permission code from your post. Step by step we can help you. There is a lot to change as you have already been able to read an answer and comments. You could already apply some.

Comment: @AKD2022 Did you see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77767523/22820043) I gave yesterday? I compiled the code against API 34, it works on an emulated device running Android 14.